# Why does this Kendo Remote View fire it's OnInit Even every time it is loaded?

Tags: kendo-mobile

I have a simple Kendo AppBuilder project with 1 Local and 2 Remote Views. The 1st Remote View is in a SubFolder.

The OnInit Event is supposed to fire once only, however on the 1st View it fires every time I navigate to it. If I move it out of the Sub Folder it seems to work as the documentation suggests (Init fires once only)

Why is this?

You can download the complete AppBuilder code here:   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12105891/TestRemoteViews.zip

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Telerik Support for this answer - I am leaving it here in case it helps someone else:

The reason for this misbehavior is the backslash in the URL.

*href="games\gamesList.html" data-icon="bookmarks">Remote View 1*

This confuses the remote view loading mechanism. Converting it to forward slash resolves the problem.

*href="games/gamesList.html" data-icon="bookmarks">Remote View 1*